# C# Trim() vs replace()

Tags: c#, string, replace, trim

In a C# `string` if we want to replace `" "` in a string to `string.empty`, is it fine to use `stringValue.Trim()` or `stringValue.replace(" ", string.empty)`. Both serve the same purpose. But which one is better?

Comment: `Trim()` removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Comment: Even if you didn't bother to look up documentation, it's already right in your intellisense. They're quite different.

Comment: Seems everybody but **Said** is ignoring the fact you can use the `Trim(char[] trimChars)`, and that `Replace(" ","")` is basically a `Trim` in disguise.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Trim()` and `Replace()` do not serve the same purpose.

`Trim()` removes all whitespace characters from the beginning and end of the string. That means `spaces`, `tabs`, `new lines`, `returns`, and other **assorted whitespace characters**.

`Replace()` only replaces the designated characters with the given replacement. So `Replace(" ", string.empty)` will only replace spaces with empty strings. Replace() also replaces all instances of the designated string with the given replacement, not just those at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Trim() can remove non-whitespace characters as well. A method overload takes an array of characters to trim.

Answer (score 16):

`String.Replace` will remove all (and only) space characters, and `String.Trim` will remove all whitespace characters from the beginning and the end of the string, not ones in the middle.

```
var tmp = "  hello world  \t";
var res1 = tmp.Trim(); // "hello world"
var res2 = tmp.Replace(" ", String.Empty); // "helloworld\t"
```

Answer (score 2):

Trim can eliminate whitespace and non-whitespace characters only from start and/or end of strings.
Replace can remove substring from any places in your string.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{{Hello World!:)".Trim('{',':',')'));  //output: Hello World
Console.WriteLine("{{Hello%World!:)".Trim('{', '%', ':',')'));  //output: Hello%World

Console.WriteLine("{{Hello World!:)".Replace("{{", string.Empty)
                                    .Replace(":)",string.Empty));  //output: Hello World

Console.WriteLine("{{Hello%World!:)".Replace("{{", string.Empty)
                                    .Replace("%", string.Empty)
                                    .Replace(":)",string.Empty));  //output: Hello World
```

TL;DR: if you want remove just single characters from start or/and end of string use `Trim()` otherwise call `Replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char [] chartrim={'*'};
string name=Console.ReadLine(); //input be *** abcd **
string result= name.Trim(chartrim);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In this case output will be `abcd`. Trim only remove the whitespace or the symbol which u want to trim from beginning and end of the string.

But in case of string.Replace() is that it will replace the string which you want to get replaced
for ex.

```
string name=Console.ReadLine(); //input be mahtab alam
string str2="khan";
string result= name.Replace("alam",str2);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In this case o/p will be `mahtab khan`.

If you want to remove space in between the strings (in this case output will be mahtabalam)

```
string name=Console.ReadLine(); //input be mahtab alam
string result= name.Replace(" ",string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Trim()` will remove only leading and trailing spaces. So you'll have to use `String.Replace()` for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Trim eliminates leading and trailing whitespace whereas Replace changes string data. It changes all occurrences of one substring into another substring. It also handles character replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Replace will replace it anywhere in the string. Trim will only trim white space from the beginning and end of the string.....So they actually do different things.

Answer (score 0):

as Nick Zimmerman said Trim() removes all whitespace characters from the beginning and end of the string. But you can use it in a different way :

Trim(char[] trimChars) which removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in the array passed in as a parameter.

[Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am well aware of the overloads for Trim(). It still does not make Trim() and Replace() equivalent. They do not serve the same purpose.